# Узнать какой класс запустил статический метод

Tags: c#

```
public class A
{
  public static Type Method()
  {
    return /*Получить тип класса*/;
  } 
}

public class B : A
{ }

public void Test()
{
  Console.WriteLine(A.Method().ToString());
  Console.WriteLine(B.Method().ToString());
}
```

Comment: никак, максимум можно получить `A`

Comment: Метод на то и статический, что он один на все экземляры и типы.

Comment: а _зачем_? Возможно вам нужен не статический метод

Comment: Сложно объяснить у меня код такой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для статического метода это сделать нельзя. Посмотрим на IL-код метода `Test`:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  call        UserQuery+A.Method
IL_0006:  callvirt    System.Object.ToString
IL_000B:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0010:  nop         
IL_0011:  call        UserQuery+A.Method
IL_0016:  callvirt    System.Object.ToString
IL_001B:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0020:  nop         
IL_0021:  ret
```

Можно видеть, что в обоих случаях вызывается метод `A.Method`: поскольку метод статический, его инструкции будут размещены в памяти в единственном экземпляре при инициализации типа A.

Comment: Вот сейчас Вы меня опечалили =(. Ну всё равно спасибо.